# TightVNC with Linux Mint & LXDE xstartup config

Tags: linux-mint, vnc, tightvnc, lxde

I have a Linux box running Linux Mint 17.2 x64 with `xfce`. For the life of me, I cannot get a proper GUI interface running when I log in to a new session via `tightvnc`. I always have a grey screen with black X as a cursor. I've tried every `xstartup` file configuration I could find with Google searches but they all result in the same (once I got a terminal window to show, but that was using gnome I believe).

Could someone show me what the `xstartup` file should look like for my setup?